# Selecting TableView cell returns incorrect object

Tags: object, uitableview, indexing

I followed a tutorial I found online to create a tableview with sections and an index from an array of custom objects. This code works with the exception that when I select a row in the table I the index path for that section and not for the entire array. I can see why it doesn't work but I can't figure out how to address the fix, this is my cell for tableview code.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"NameCell";


UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}



// Configure the cell...


    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    int displayOrder = [defaults integerForKey:@"displayOrder"];
    int sortOrder = [defaults integerForKey:@"sortOrder"];

    NSString *alphabet = [listIndex objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]];

    NSPredicate *sectionPredicate = [[NSPredicate alloc] init];

    if (sortOrder == 1) {  
        //NSLog(@"fName is predicate at cell level");
        sectionPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fName beginswith[c] %@", alphabet];
    } else {
        //NSLog(@"lName is predicate at cell level");
        sectionPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lName beginswith[c] %@", alphabet];
    }
    NSArray *sectionContacts = [filteredList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:sectionPredicate];

if (isSearching) {
    current = [filteredList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
} else{
    current = [sectionContacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];        
}

if (displayOrder == 1) {
    NSString *fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[current valueForKey:@"fName"],[current valueForKey:@"lName"]];
    [cell.textLabel setText:fullName];  
    //NSLog(@"FirstNameFirst");

} else {
    NSString *fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@",[current valueForKey:@"lName"],[current valueForKey:@"fName"]];
    [cell.textLabel setText:fullName];
    //NSLog(@"LastNameFirst");

}

    [cell.detailTextLabel setText:[current valueForKey:@"extension"]];

return cell;  }
```

THen I call the segue with this code.

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showContact"]) {

    DetailViewController *dvc = [segue destinationViewController];
    NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    NSDictionary *c = [filteredList objectAtIndex:path.row];
    [dvc setCurrentContact:c];   
    [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
} }
```

The problem is that the objectAtIndex:path.row returns the index for that section but it isn't modified for the entire array, so if a name in the "B" section that is at index 4 of that section is tapped it returns the object at index 4 of the primary array. I have been scratching my head to figure out how to get the index for the full array and not for the one that is only local to that section.

I'll buy you a 6 pack of your favorite beverage if you can help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do it the same way that they do it in the first function, so change your prepareForSegue to this:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showContact"]) {
        DetailViewController *dvc = [segue destinationViewController];
        NSIndexPath *path = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        NSDictionary *c;
        NSString *alphabet = [listIndex objectAtIndex:[path section]];
        NSPredicate *sectionPredicate = [[NSPredicate alloc] init];
        if (sortOrder == 1) {  
            sectionPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"fName beginswith[c] %@", alphabet];
        } else {
            sectionPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"lName beginswith[c] %@", alphabet];
        }
        NSArray *sectionContacts = [filteredList filteredArrayUsingPredicate:sectionPredicate];

        if (isSearching) {
            c = [filteredList objectAtIndex:path.row];
        } else{
            c = [sectionContacts objectAtIndex:path.row];        
        }

        [dvc setCurrentContact:c];   
        [searchBar resignFirstResponder];
    } 
}
```

Note that it would probably be best to pull the common code out and make a separate function  instead of using it twice like this.

Comment: You sir, have made my day! I'm still pretty new to objective C and have been having trouble understanding just what information is sent in some of these calls. I didn't know that I would be able to pull the `[listIndex objectAtIndex:[path section]];` would still return the right letter. Thank you so much for your help.